# Bash command to copy and rename same filename in many directories?

Tags: bash, command-line

If I have:

```
Images
    1234
        base.jpg
        small.jpg
    5678
        base.jpg
    9012
        base.jpg
    3456
        base.jpg
        small.jpg
```

I would like to run a command that would navigate through this dir structure, find base.jpg and copy it as small.jpg if small.jpg doesn't exist in the same dir. I have around 1700+ dir with these images and I want any dir without a small to get base.jpg copied and renamed.

Any command for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about using `find` with `execdir`:

```
find Images -name "base.jpg" -execdir cp -n {} small.jpg \;
```

This searches in the `Images` directory for files with the name `base.jpg`. For each file that it finds, it attempts to copy it to a file called `small.jpg` in the same directory. The `-n` switch to `cp` prevents existing files from being overwritten.

Comment: Fast and awesome. I'm real glad you were here today.